# RegularExpression не работает

Tags: регулярные-выражения, asp.net-mvc

Для валидации данных проверяю, чтобы в номере содержались только цифры, но почему-то не работает.
Например, при вводе 234, выдает заданный error message

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Номер может содержать только цифры")]
```

Comment: Протестируйте свое регулярное выражение здесь https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2):

Думаю стоит попробовать

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Номер может содержать только цифры")]
```

Comment: Стоит добавить, что [0-9] - это значит один символ, поэтому не проходят строки длиной больше. а [0-9]+ значит как минимум один символ, и строка неограниченной длины.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте и вот такой вариант, поддерживает и знак плюса перед номером

```
\+[0-9]+|[0-9]+
```